# Unable to run GCP DataflowTemplates locally

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I'm trying to run PubSubToBigQuery.java locally using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates with direct runner. However I'm getting the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery$Options missing a property named 'gcs-location'.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1518)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:294)
    at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.main(PubSubToBigQuery.java:165)
```

But I've already passed `--gcs-location=gs://xxx-templates/dataflow/pipelines/pubsub-to-bigquery` during run.

It is at this line the error is thrown. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L176

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the args passed to the Java application with the args passed to run the templated pipeline via the CLI.

`--gcs-location` is what you pass to `gcloud dataflow jobs run` on the CLI. When you run the Java app, Dataflow stages your pipeline on GCS (the template), but doesn't run the pipeline immediately. `--gcs-location` is telling `gcloud dataflow..` the location of the template to run.

You can't execute a templated pipeline locally. You just run the staging of the template locally via the Java app.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates

```
 * # Set the runner
 * RUNNER=DataflowRunner
 *
 * # Build the template <--NOTE THIS
 * mvn compile exec:java \
 * -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery \
 * -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
 * -Dexec.args=" \
 * --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
 * --stagingLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/staging \
 * --tempLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/temp \
 * --templateLocation=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/template \
 * --runner=${RUNNER}"
 *
 * # Execute the template <--NOTE THIS
 * JOB_NAME=pubsub-to-bigquery-$USER-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%z"`
 *
 * gcloud dataflow jobs run ${JOB_NAME} \
 * --gcs-location=${PIPELINE_FOLDER}/template \
 * --zone=us-east1-d \
 * --parameters \
 * "inputTopic=projects/data-analytics-pocs/topics/teleport-pubsub-to-bigquery,\
 * outputTableSpec=data-analytics-pocs:demo.pubsub_to_bigquery,\
 * outputDeadletterTable=data-analytics-pocs:demo.pubsub_to_bigquery_deadletter"
 * </pre>
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would I be able to run the staging of the template locally? I'm unable to build template using DirectRunner.

Comment: You just run the Java app like any other app locally and it will stage the template on GCS.

Comment: Templates are a concept that is unique to Dataflow as far as I'm aware, so Dataflow is the only runner that can produce a template, and the template always has to be staged to GCS. There's no concept of staging a template to the local filesystem, and Dataflow would not be able to access a locally staged template.